# How to write this sql statement without NOT?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query - I need to have period less than valid_to unless `ou_code = 'OU140'` and `acc_lev6_code = 'A4900'`.

My query returns correct results, but I just want to write it without `NOT`'s. I just can't seem to figure this out because if I write a statement that period is less than `valid_to` I can't seem to write a statement that would make the data set wider.
Edit : without using OR?

```
with table1 (ou_code, acc_lev6_code, period, valid_to) as (
   select 'OU140', 'A4900', 201509, 201506  from dual union all  
   select 'OU140', 'A4900', 201510, 201505 from dual union all   
   select 'OU150', 'A4900', 201509, 201506 from dual union all   
   select 'OU165', 'A5200', 201509, 999999  from dual union all  
   select 'OU100', 'A5000', 201509, 201503 from dual union all   
   select 'OU150', 'A4900', 201609, 201506 from dual union all   
   select 'OU100', 'A5000', 201509, 999999 from dual union all   
   select 'OU100', 'A4900', 201509, 201506 from dual union all   
   select 'OU140', 'A5000', 201509, 999999 from dual             
 )

 select 
*
 from table1 a
 where 
 NOT (a.period >= a.valid_to AND NOT(a.acc_lev6_code='A4900' AND a.ou_code='OU140'))
```

Comment: Why do you want to write it without NOT or OR? It's not clear what you mean by "make the data set wider"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using d'Morgan law:

```
(a.period < a.valid_to OR (a.acc_lev6_code='A4900' AND a.ou_code='OU140'))
```

Suppose `A : a.period < a.valid_to` and `B : a.acc_lev6_code='A4900'` and `C = a.ou_code:'OU140'`

```
NOT(A AND NOT(B AND C)) = (NOT A OR NOT(NOT(B AND C)))
= (NOT A OR (B AND C))
```

and

```
NOT A : a.period < a.valid_to
```

so

```
(NOT A AND (B AND C)) = 
(a.period < a.valid_to OR (a.acc_lev6_code='A4900' AND a.ou_code='OU140'))
```

Comment: And without OR? not possible?

Comment: @user3014914, the actual query has no `OR` in it.

Answer (score 2):

By applying [De Morgan's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Substitution_form) subsitution principle you can transform your where clause to

```
a.period > a.valid_to OR (a.acc_lev6_code='A4900' AND a.ou_code='OU140')
```

`NOT ( x AND y )` is equivalent to `NOT x OR NOT y`